# even small file upload stops activity on apache/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, file-upload, paperclip

on my rails(2.3.5) app(currently 50-70rpm, maximum response time around 0.7s), uploading even 700k file(using paperclip plugin) locks up the server for web requests for everyone for 2 minutes! (other apps on same server work normally)

does anyone have a clue why that might be happening? i am using some mysql transactions which lock the database also if that might be an issue

i read http://www.therailsway.com/2009/4/23/uploading-files
but it couldn't be locking server for 2 minutes for a small file, could it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, obviously the problem was the one in the article - rails locking up after a file upload. seems that installing mod porter fixed it.

upd:switched to nginx upload module which is even faster.