# How to upload large file in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am Using Rails 3.0.9 , Ruby 1.9.3p0 
I am trying to upload a zip/tar file to server.
When i am uploading file 2.5mb. Evey thing works fine. But when i am uplaoing a zip file of 350mb. It creates error.(network error connection time out/ or "aborted" in response of firebug) .
In apache config, i had increased timeout from 300 from 300000 but nothing happened.
Is this possibly an apache setting? Or could it be something on their end? Any suggestions on where I should look would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have used both apache and Nginx.  For such big file uploads i prefer NGINX.  If you use Nginx you can set [client_max_body_size](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size) to something like `500 MB` inside your `nginx.conf` . One of the question who prefers the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591574/even-small-file-upload-stops-activity-on-apache-rails) .